# Array.prototype.map, and the difference between these two examples

Tags: javascript, arrays

Both calls to Array.prototype.map in the below code return the array [2, 4, 6]. Explain the subtle difference between the two lines of code. Which one is the preferred option, and why?

```
[1, 2, 3].map(n => n *= 2);

[1, 2, 3].map(n => n * 2);
```

I've tried to think about one as re-assignment and the other as mutation

Comment: The first one mutates the `n` parameter, but since the scope of the callback ends there, that updated variable is lost, so the update is pointless.

Comment: You're basically asking what `*=` does. This isn't actually specific to `.map()`.

Answer (score 0):

For your first case, you are reassigning `n` but that side effect isn't really visible since `n` is discarded.

Answer (score 0):

The first line can be written as below. So you are just reassigning n

```
console.log([1, 2, 3].map(n => n = n*2));// Like this just reassigning n with n*2 after every iteration

console.log([1, 2, 3].map(n => n * 2));
```

Answer (score 0):

There's should be no difference at all.
The reason why both give the same result is that `.map()` always returns a new array populated with the results of the given function; the caveat here is that the **result of the assignment operator is the assigned value itself**, in fact, if you run

```
let x = 5;
console.log(x = 4);
```

You get 4 as output.

By following this behavior:

- `n => n * 2` - will put the result of `n * 2` in the corresponding array cell
- `n => n *= 2` - will put the result of `n *= 2` in the corresponding array cell, and the result is exactly `n * 2`